# Flask routes and views

Tags: python, flask

Basically I'm trying to create a view that lets the user update his password.

Code below.

```
@app.route('/update_login_info/<password>',methods=['GET','POST'])
def update_login_info(password):
   form = forms.UpdateLoginForm()
   if form.validate_on_submit():
      try:
         query=models.User.update(password=models.generate_password_hash(form.new_password.data),)
         query.execute()
         flash("login info updated","success")
         return redirect(url_for('login'))
      except:
         flash("error updating login info","error")
         return redirect(url_for('login'))
   return render_template('update_login_info.html',form=form)
```

every time i get to the route flask throws a 404 and i cannot work out why.

When the user clicks on a link in their email the route looks like this 
http://chdbfiletransferapp/update_login_info/$2a$12$HdJJbOUwALvtUjrlKhIrYeJdMO3nws0hAQ94/6I/dU8IaSAtdU6W6

Comment: Your link should not be recognized as a valid route, since it contains special characters like slash in the <password> part

Comment: thanks Timo I figured it could possibly be the special characters. Changed it now to pass the user id as a query string and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Use path converter to accept slashes:

```
@app.route('/update_login_info/<path:password>',methods=['GET','POST'])
```

Comment: it was not the slashes rather the special characters in the query string i was passing. Got it working now thanks